# Variable in makefile needed in csh

Tags: makefile, csh

I have a variable in a makefile that holds a value.

Example in `MakefileA.mk`:

```
VAR1 = 1
```

This value needs to be used in a csh file, for example `CshA.csh`:

```
if ($VAR1) then
```

How can you include the makefile in the csh or extract the value of VAR1 to be used in the csh file?

Comment: Which `make` are you using? Some support `-V VARNAME` to print out the value (e.g. BSD make), but GNU make doesn't, although you [can use hacks](https://blog.melski.net/2010/11/30/makefile-hacks-print-the-value-of-any-variable/).

Comment: "make -f MakefileA". I was thinking if i can move it to the environment variables, could the csh file use it then?

Comment: Please share the section of the makefile, which is invoking the `CshA.csh` script. It will make it easier to provide a solution.

Comment: How are you thinking to invoke your shell file, from the makefile or outside of the makefile? Are you able to modify the makefile? Need to know more context/constraints.

Comment: @dash-o , ryu1kn : the csh script file invokes the makefile(make -f MakefileA). After the makefile has been executed, a variable set in the makefile needs to be used in the script further.

Comment: Thanks @AlphaGoku . Is editing the makefile an option? If so, and if it's fine to write the value to a temporary file, you can do so with `$(shell echo $(VAR1) > var1.txt)` at the top-level, or `@echo $(VAR1) > var1.txt` in the make rule that is invoked, and read the file in your script.

Comment: No process can set a variable in the environment of any other running process, but your `make` run could output the value, through one channel or another, so that the script could capture it or read it back to set the variable itself.

Comment: @AlphaGoku might be a good idea to post the clarification into the question. The current question can be misinterpreted.

Comment: @ryu1kn - Seems like a good solution. What command would i need to do in the make file to output the value to the .txt file. How would i then include this .txt file in the csh file and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised based on input from OP:

Consider adding a target to the make file to query the "var1"

```
query-var1:
    @echo $(VAR1)
```

Then in the  CshA.csh script, use the target to query the variable

```
...
make -f MakefileA
set VAR1=`make -f MakefileA query-var1`
if ($VAR1) then
   ...
endif
```

Comment: Good answer, if only it matched the target usage, as clarified later by the OP in comments.  Evidently, they actually want to convey the variable in question to the shell that executed `make`, not one that `make` executes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for pointing the additional information, answer revised for additional information

Comment: when i did echo $VAR1, it printed the statement make -f MakefileA query-var1

Comment: i also tried executing make -f MakefileA query-var1 directly in the csh. I get the error : no rule to make target 'query'

Comment: @AlphaGoku Please make sure you use back quote \`make ...\`, and not forward quotes 'make ...'. The back quotes will be replaced with the output of the make command. The forward quote (or double quotes) will treat the 'make ...' as  a string